# T-SQL EXEC to DB2 with parameters and wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, db2, wildcard

I have this code that forms part of a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure that queries data from an IBM DB2 database, but it is not working.

```
    @Search nvarchar(50) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC('select mbwhlo as Store,
                 mbitno as SKU,
                 mmitds as Description,
                 mwwhnm as StoreName,
                 mbstqt as Qty,
                 SUBSTRING(mbitno, 12, 4) AS Size
          from m3fdbprod.mitbal
          left outer join m3fdbprod.mitwhl on mbcono = mwcono AND mbwhlo = mwwhlo
          left outer join m3fdbprod.mitmas on mbcono = mmcono AND mbitno = mmitno
          where mbcono = 1
            and mbitno = ?
             or mmitds = ?
             or mwwhnm = ?
             or mmitds = ?
          order by mbitno, mbwhlo', '%' + @Search +'%',+'%'@Search+'%',+'%'@Search+'%',+'%'@Search+'%') AT LawsonDR
```

I get this  message:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: what's the comma after the `order by` doing there?. Also, you should concatenate the string first, and then execute that string. And, why are you using dynamic SQL in the first place?, doesn't seem necessary

Comment: the comma is there as when you use an EXEC you put the parameters after it.  Each of the 4 ? must tally up to the four @ that are passed.